# How read multiple inputs from one line in java?

Tags: java

So i have this code :

```
for(int i=0;i<number;i++) { 
System.out.println("WHAT HOUSEHOLD DO YOU WANT TO CONNECT IN APARTMENT NO."+(i+1));
        System.out.println("1 ) OVEN");
        System.out.println("2 ) TV");
        System.out.println("3 ) VACCUUM CLEANER");
        System.out.println("4 ) REFRIGERATOR");
        int option = cin.nextInt();
        switch(option) {
        case 1: {
            for(initiereAparate e : aparate)
            fw.write((i+1)+" "+e.ob1.denumire+" "+e.ob1.material+" "+e.ob1.culoare+" "+e.ob1.origine+" "+e.ob1.consumEnergie+"\r\n"); break;
        }
        case 2: {
            for(initiereAparate e : aparate)
            fw.write((i+1)+" "+e.ob2.denumire+" "+e.ob2.material+" "+e.ob2.culoare+" "+e.ob2.origine+" "+e.ob2.consumEnergie+"\r\n"); break;
        }
        case 3: {
            for(initiereAparate e : aparate)
            fw.write((i+1)+" "+e.ob3.denumire+" "+e.ob3.material+" "+e.ob3.culoare+" "+e.ob3.origine+" "+e.ob3.consumEnergie+"\r\n"); break;
        }
        case 4: {
            for(initiereAparate e : aparate)
            fw.write((i+1)+" "+e.ob4.denumire+" "+e.ob4.material+" "+e.ob4.culoare+" "+e.ob4.origine+" "+e.ob4.consumEnergie+"\r\n"); break;
        }
        }
}
```

I would like to know how to read multiple inputs.For example i will type in one line 1 2 4 , and this numbers will execute 3 cases at once.In my code that i already have i can type only 1 number and it will execute only one case statement

Comment: You'd have to read the whole line with `cin.nextLine()` then split the resulting string, then convert each sub string to `int`.

Comment: Note, you could skip the conversion to `int` and just use the string: `case "1":`

Comment: Style note: brackets `{ }` on the case statements are not needed here. Brackets on `for` loops are [preferred](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.1-braces) (though strictly not required here).

Comment: Why is your program shouting at you? (All caps is considered shouting.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to change your input function to expect a string rather than an int. And then simply split your string into number and loop trought the number to execute your switch case.

**P.S** please note that this code is untested, don't just copy and paste it expecting everything to work perfectly. Try to understand what I did and apply it to your own context.

```
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        System.out.println("WHAT HOUSEHOLD DO YOU WANT TO CONNECT IN APARTMENT NO." + (i + 1));
        System.out.println("1 ) OVEN");
        System.out.println("2 ) TV");
        System.out.println("3 ) VACCUUM CLEANER");
        System.out.println("4 ) REFRIGERATOR");
        // we change this to nextLine() because we want a string.
        String option = cin.nextLine();
        // we split our string at white space, this give us an array of string;
        String[] options = option.split("\\s+");
        // we parse every options in the array
        for (int j = 0; j < options.length; j++) {
            // we need to cast the option back to an integer since, it's what we are
            // comparing.
            int currentOption = Integer.parseInt(options[j]);
            switch (currentOption) {
            case 1: {
                for (initiereAparate e : aparate)
                    fw.write((i + 1) + " " + e.ob1.denumire + " " + e.ob1.material + " " + e.ob1.culoare + " "
                            + e.ob1.origine + " " + e.ob1.consumEnergie + "\r\n");
                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                for (initiereAparate e : aparate)
                    fw.write((i + 1) + " " + e.ob2.denumire + " " + e.ob2.material + " " + e.ob2.culoare + " "
                            + e.ob2.origine + " " + e.ob2.consumEnergie + "\r\n");
                break;
            }
            case 3: {
                for (initiereAparate e : aparate)
                    fw.write((i + 1) + " " + e.ob3.denumire + " " + e.ob3.material + " " + e.ob3.culoare + " "
                            + e.ob3.origine + " " + e.ob3.consumEnergie + "\r\n");
                break;
            }
            case 4: {
                for (initiereAparate e : aparate)
                    fw.write((i + 1) + " " + e.ob4.denumire + " " + e.ob4.material + " " + e.ob4.culoare + " "
                            + e.ob4.origine + " " + e.ob4.consumEnergie + "\r\n");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As [Arvind Kumar Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10819573/arvind-kumar-avinash)
 pointed out in the comment, it is important to add the keyword `break` to you switch cases, this ensure that you only treat one case per iteration.

Comment: Make sure you put `break` in each `case`. Also, add `default` to show the relevant message when the user selects a number other than 1 to 4.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash You are right, let me add that in. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: The `break` statements are there. Just hidden at the end of the line.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp - you are right. Nicolas - I've formatted your code to make it visible.

Comment: @Nicolas I'am getting java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" , something with this line int currentOption = Integer.parseInt(options[j]);

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. You can use following idea:

```
String option = cin.nextLine();
String[] data=option.split(" ") // split by space character
for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
int option = Integer.parseInt(data[i]);
switch(option)...}
```

Comment: Please note that OP is already using `i` as their loop variable. You might want to change it to something else.

Comment: Yes, you are right. @Nicolas you can use any other variable name: i,j,k..